# Clone Github repository for manos

Tags: github, manos

I thought this would be really easy, but I'm failing to clone http://github.com/jacksonh/manos so I can build the project.

```
[dev@vps ~]$ git clone http://github.com/jacksonh/manos
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dev/manos/.git/
```

The above never returns and never creates any directories.  I can browse the source using the http address, but I'm not sure how to get the git cloned?

Comment: This command works fine for me. Do you use proxy? Or can you check with strace where git is stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
git clone https://github.com/jacksonh/manos.git
```

It did for me:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jacksonh/manos.git
Cloning into 'manos'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 9805, done.
remote: Counting objects: 34, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Total 9839 (delta 8), reused 10 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (9839/9839), 5.28 MiB | 1.99 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5128/5128), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Comment: If you look at my question I was missing "https", I had "http".  It didn't give me any error, it just sat there!  It works with "https". Thanks, all set!